# speech recognition in java

Tags: java, speech-recognition, javax.speech

I want to use speech recognition in my project and I found this code but when I run it I get an error which is:

> ```
> run: java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at newpackage.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:55)
> ```

Please could one of you help me in this problem?

This is the server code that I use:

```
package newpackage;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.speech.*;
import javax.speech.recognition.*;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Locale;

public class HelloWorld extends ResultAdapter {
  static Recognizer rec;

  // Receives RESULT_ACCEPTED event: print it, clean up, exit
  public void resultAccepted(ResultEvent e) {
    Result r = (Result)(e.getSource());
    ResultToken tokens[] = r.getBestTokens();

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
      System.out.print(tokens[i].getSpokenText() + " ");

    System.out.println();
    try {
          // Deallocate the recognizer and exit
          rec.deallocate();
    } catch (EngineException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (EngineStateError ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.exit(0);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      // Create a recognizer that supports English.
      rec = Central.createRecognizer(
              new EngineModeDesc(Locale.ENGLISH));

      // Start up the recognizer
      rec.allocate();

      // Load the grammar from a file, and enable it
      FileReader reader = new FileReader(args[0]);
      RuleGrammar gram = rec.loadJSGF(reader);

      gram.setEnabled(true);

      // Add the listener to get results
      rec.addResultListener(new HelloWorld());

      // Commit the grammar
      rec.commitChanges();

      // Request focus and start listening
      rec.requestFocus();
      rec.resume();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
          // System.out.println("the problem");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (rec != null) {
    System.out.println(rec);
}
else {
    System.out.println("rec is null");   
    // <-- here's your problem.  you need to return, exit, or throw here!
}

// Start up the recognizer
rec.allocate();  // <-- This is the line that's blowing out (I assume)
```

You'll get a null pointer because even though your else is handling the case when `rec` is null, your program continues.  You need to return or exit, or something when `rec` is null.

**Note:** Also, I reformatted your code because it's hard to read your if/else.  If you're going to use curlies on one branch of your if/else, you should use curlies on both.  It makes it more readable.

**Edit:** Oh yeah, as far as why `createRecognizer` is returning `null`, I'm afraid I don't know.

Comment: Now I see the error. Should have seen that, too, but I was too confused with that indention and the two curly braces at the end.

Answer (score 2):

rewrite the

```
// Create a recognizer that supports English.
      rec = Central.createRecognizer(
              new EngineModeDesc(Locale.ENGLISH));
```

to be as below

```
            SynthesizerModeDesc desc = new SynthesizerModeDesc(
            null,          // engine name
            "general",     // mode name
            Locale.US,     // locale
            null,          // running
            null);         // voice

     synth = Central.createSynthesizer(desc);
```

Comment: @Alessandro Minoccheri , And where I can download all libraries .jar that I need