# Exception in java speech recognition

Tags: java, speech-recognition

I am facing some exception in the following code :

```
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Locale;
    import javax.speech.AudioException;
    import javax.speech.Central;
    import javax.speech.EngineException;
    import javax.speech.EngineModeDesc;
    import javax.speech.EngineStateError;
    import javax.speech.recognition.GrammarException;
    import javax.speech.recognition.Recognizer;
    import javax.speech.recognition.Result;
    import javax.speech.recognition.ResultAdapter;
    import javax.speech.recognition.ResultEvent;
    import javax.speech.recognition.ResultToken;
    import javax.speech.recognition.RuleGrammar;

    public class HelloWorld extends ResultAdapter {

        static Recognizer rec;

        // Receives RESULT_ACCEPTED event: print it, clean up, exit
        @Override
        public void resultAccepted(ResultEvent e) {
            Result r = (Result) (e.getSource());
            ResultToken tokens[] = r.getBestTokens();

            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(tokens[i].getSpokenText() + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            try {
                // Deallocate the recognizer and exit
                rec.deallocate();
            } catch (EngineException | EngineStateError ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            try {
                // Create a recognizer that supports English.
                rec = Central.createRecognizer(
                        new EngineModeDesc(Locale.ENGLISH));

                // Start up the recognizer
                rec.allocate();

                // Load the grammar from a file, and enable it
                FileReader reader = new FileReader(args[0]);
                RuleGrammar gram = rec.loadJSGF(reader);
                gram.setEnabled(true);

                // Add the listener to get results
                rec.addResultListener(new HelloWorld());

                // Commit the grammar
                rec.commitChanges();

                // Request focus and start listening
                rec.requestFocus();
                rec.resume();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | EngineException | SecurityException | GrammarException | IOException | AudioException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Exception:-
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Demo5.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:55)
Java Result: 1

Exception occured in this line (line 55):

```
// Start up the recognizer
 rec.allocate();
```

Comment: where is line 55 in your code?

Comment: why you define this variable static? static Recognizer rec;

Comment: I have tried to make this variable (static Recognizer rec;) non static but still it throwing the same exception..

Comment: Defining `rec` as static won't cause any issues.

Comment: I think it is the source of your problem but how you change it to non static?

Comment: why you allocate rec twice in your code? why you never used resultAccepted inside your main method?

Answer (score 0):

The `Recognizer` appears to be null. See this line:

```
rec = Central.createRecognizer(new EngineModeDesc(Locale.ENGLISH));
```

The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapi-doc/javax/speech/Central.html#createRecognizer(javax.speech.EngineModeDesc)) suggest that this is a problem with the arguments you are providing to `createRecognizer`:

> If there is no Recognizer with the required properties the method returns null.

As for fixing the cause of the null Recognizer, the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769523/speech-recognition-in-java) may be helpful.

Comment: if you mean defiening  variable, he has already done that and type is static

Comment: No, the exception is occurring on the line immediately after he assigns `rec` the value of `Central.createRecognizer(new EngineModeDesc(Locale.ENGLISH));`. The problem is with the call to `createRecognizer`.